# Allowing only letters and numbers for not required field?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using Jquery validation plugin to validate the form fields. I've scenario where we need to validate the field to allow only alphabets and numbers if it's typed and that field is not required.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-msg-required="Enter your last name" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
```

I've code that do accept only letters and numbers. But, if i use, it makes the field mandatory even if i set required to false.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
  return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
}, "Please enter a valid name");


  lastname: {
            accept: "[a-zA-Z]+"
        }
```

Simply i don't want to run the validate script in rules until someone types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've code that do accept only letters and numbers. But, if I use, it makes the field mandatory even if I set `required` to `false`.

That's because your custom rule does not care if the field is blank.  You've written it so that a blank value is also evaluated.

> Simply I don't want to run the validate script in rules until someone types.

You need to also check `this.optional(element)` to make sure the field is not set to `required`  (then it can pass validation when the field is left blank).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("accept", function(value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
}, "Please enter a valid name");
```

---

> Allowing only letters and numbers for not required field?

You did not need to write a custom method for this.  You could have just used the `alphanumeric` method from [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js).

Comment: Nice. But, what should i do if it accept only alphabelts?

Comment: @user3289108, there is also a method called `lettersonly` contained within the `additional-methods.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it on your own and not using the plugin like this:

```
$('input').on('keypress',function(e){
    if(!/([a-zA-Z0-9])+/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it by myself.

```
function lastnameRequired() {
    return $('#lastname').val().length > 0;
}

 lastname: {

              required: lastnameRequired,
                accept: {
                param: "[a-zA-Z]+",
                depends: lastnameRequired
             }
            },
```

The above code solves my problem. Hope it helps others!

Comment: **WAY too verbose**.   You need to simply fix your custom method so that it checks to see if the field is "optional".  The  `required`, `depends`, and `lastnameRequired` are not needed.